# TAB key not working under citrix environment using PyAutoGUI

Tags: python, python-2.7, citrix, pyautogui

I am trying to fill a login form in Citrix environment using PyAutoGUI. But I am unable to press `TAB` key to switch form fields. Keys like `Enter` is working properly.

Manually `TAB` is working on that form but it is not working using PyAutoGUI. Below is the code I am trying.

```
time.sleep(10)
im9 = pyautogui.screenshot()
im9 = np.array(im9)

# locate_image locates image on current screen
username_sp = fi.locate_image(im9, 'Screenshot.png')
if username_sp:
    pyautogui.typewrite('Username\t',interval=1)
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.press('tab')
    pyautogui.typewrite(r'pass',interval=0.25)
```

But, `user` and `pass` get clubbed into single Username field. On normal environment `TAB` is working Ok.

Comment: don't you just _hate_ citrix ?

Comment: Did you try to add a `sleep` _after_ sending tab? and send more tabs just to see what it is doing?

Comment: Yeah, I tried to send multiple tabs but same result. Didn't tried sleep after tab will try and update you.

Comment: Tried. It didn't helped. :(

Comment: could you locate the login window and send a mouse click instead? citrix sucks, It handles the events in an "optimized" way so GTK apps tend to lock up/freeze for instance.

Comment: Yes, I do. I tried using [`uipath`](https://www.uipath.com/). It is working and I am able to press TAB through it. May be there is some bug with `PyAutoGUI`.

Comment: Finally, `pywinauto` worked for me. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

Running into the same issue it looks like how pyautogui sends tab just doesn't work with Citrix. I have been able to send tab with keyboard though.

```py
import keyboard
keyboard.press_and_release('tab')
```